# Check output of a python command

Tags: python

I have a python script which tries to run an external command and look for result of the command. And it needs to use the value 'count=' from the output of the external command

```
COUNT_EXP = re.compile("count=(.*)")
cmd = [] # external command
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
          result = COUNT_EXP.match(line)
          if result:
              print "count= " + result.group(1)
              return int(result.group(1))
```

When I try to run my script, my external command ("cmd") got execute and I see count=10 in the shell. But why my python can't find that and print out "count= 10? in the 'if' clause above?

Comment: your if clause probably evaluates to False, thus you never print the count. Maybe your python working directory does not contain the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python','blah.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if len(line) != 0:
    print "success"  #if this code works, expanding to your regex should also work
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following C program:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    printf ("count=199");
    return 0;
}
```

... which I called `countOutput.c` and the following Python script, modified from yours:

```
import subprocess, re

COUNT_EXP = re.compile("count=(.*)")
cmd = "./countOutput" # external command
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    result = COUNT_EXP.match(line)
    if result:
        print "count is equal to " + result.group(1)
```

... which I called `countTest.py`, and then ran:

```
$ python countTest.py
count is equal to 199
```

... which all works as expected. I'd therefore tend to agree with @kichik in thinking that the external command that you're using may be writing to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be printing that to `stderr`. Try redirecting that one to `PIPE` as well and read data from there. You can also append `2>&1` to the end of the command to get `stderr` redirected to `stdout` by the shell. You might have to add `shell=True` for that.